# sql extract rightmost number in string and increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, increment

i have transaction codes like

```
 "A0004", "1B2005","20CCCCCCC21"
```

I need to extract the rightmost number and increment the transaction code by one

```
"AA0004"----->"AA0005"
"1B2005"------->"1B2006"
"20CCCCCCCC21"------>"20CCCCCCCC22"
```

in SQL Server 2012.

- unknown length of string
- right(n?) always number

dealing with unsignificant number of string and number length is out of my league. 
some logic is always missing.

```
LEFT(@a,2)+RIGHT('000'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING(@a,2,4),2,3))+1)),3
```

Comment: Another good example why you shouldn't combine different types of information in the same column

Comment: `SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE('20CCCCCCCC12345'), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE('20CCCCCCCC12345')) - 1))`. And now you know why you should never want to do string manipulation in T-SQL. Incrementing it *as a number* and giving it back the original number of digits is left as an exercise to the reader (that's no picnic either). If at all possible, extract this data on insertion into its own column. It's only painful once, then you profit from it forever.

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to be clear about this: I totally agree with the comments to the question from a_horse_with_no_name and Jeroen Mostert.
You should be storing one data point per column, period.

Having said that, I do realize that a lot of times the database structure can't be changed - so here's one possible way to get that calculation for you.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE 
(
    col varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @T (col) VALUES
('A0004'),
('1B2005'),
('1B2000'),
('1B00'),
('20CCCCCCC21');
```

(I've added a couple of strings as edge cases you didn't mention in the question)

Then, using a couple of `cross apply` to minimize code repetition, I came up with that:

```
SELECT  col,
        LEFT(col, LEN(col) - LastCharIndex + 1) + 
        REPLICATE('0', LEN(NumberString) - LEN(CAST(NumberString as int))) + 
        CAST((CAST(NumberString as int) + 1) as varchar(100)) As Result
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Reverse(col)) As LastCharIndex
) As Idx
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT RIGHT(col, LastCharIndex - 1) As NumberString
) As NS
```

Results:

```
col         Result
A0004       A0005
1B2005      1B2006
1B2000      1B2001
1B00        1B01
20CCCCCCC21 20CCCCCCC22
```

The `LastCharIndex` represents the index of the last non-digit char in the string.
The `NumberString` represents the number to increment, as a string (to preserve the leading zeroes if they exists).

From there, it's simply taking the left part of the string (that is, up until the number), and concatenate it to a newly calculated number string, using `Replicate` to pad the result of addition with the exact number of leading zeroes the original number string had.

Comment: Worth noting that this turns `20CCCCCCC99` into `20CCCCCCC100`. That's arguably the best this code can do, but possibly not what's expected. This gets especially pernicious when combined with T-SQL's eagerness to truncate strings -- it could inadvertently end up as `20CCCCCCC10` when further processed.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank you.it works . the solution is too complex for me. can you help creating this into a sql function.input "A0004" output to "A0005" and like that...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DECLARE @test nvarchar(1000) ='"A0004", "1B2005","20CCCCCCC21"'
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY,Data nvarchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @Temp 
SELECT @test

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT Id,LTRIM(RTRIM((REPLACE(Split.a.value('.' ,' nvarchar(max)'),'"',''))))  AS Data
,RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM((REPLACE(Split.a.value('.' ,' nvarchar(max)'),'"','')))),1)+1 AS ReqData
FROM
(
SELECT ID,
CAST ('<S>'+REPLACE(Data,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML) AS Data
FROM @Temp
) AS A
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('S') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT CONCAT('"'+Data+'"','-------->','"'+CONCAT(LEFT(Data,LEN(Data)-1),CAST(ReqData AS VARCHAR))+'"') AS ExpectedResult
FROM CTE
```

### Result

```
ExpectedResult
-----------------
"A0004"-------->"A0005"
"1B2005"-------->"1B2006"
"20CCCCCCC21"-------->"20CCCCCCC22"
```

Comment: Fails on any string ending in 9.

Answer (score 0):

STUFF(@X
,LEN(@X)-CASE PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',REVERSE(@X)) WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@X) ELSE PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',REVERSE(@X))-1 END+1
,LEN(((RIGHT(@X,CASE PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',REVERSE(@X)) WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@X) ELSE PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',REVERSE(@X))-1 END)/@N)+1)*@N)
,((RIGHT(@X,CASE PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',REVERSE(@X)) WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@X) ELSE PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',REVERSE(@X))-1 END)/@N)+1)*@N)

- works on number only strings
- 99 becomes 100
- mod(@N) increments